# Why does the Ciphar 10 tutorial on TensorFlow crop the images to be 24x24?

Tags: data-transformation, dataset, deep-learning, data-preprocessing, data-augmentation

I was going over [the cifar 10 tutorial in tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn/#model_inputs) and was trying to understand why the guys in tensorflow/google decided to crop the images. The only reason I could justify it to myself is because they wanted to possibly decrease the computation time when training the neural net, otherwise it seems rather random.

I've talked with colleges and they imply it has to do with data set augmentation, however, data set augmentation can be done, regardless the size of the original image (to my understanding).

My initial guess of why they might be cropping and then augmenting the data set (with flips, brightness changes and contrasts) is because they want to get the actual image object and ignore the surroundings and then apply the transformation. If that were the goal, then for me what would have made sense is to not apply a random crop as they are doing (otherwise how do you know you are getting the actual object?) and then do the data set augmentation. Since thats not whats happening, I have my doubts, that my guess is correct.

Can someone clarify why the cropping is being done? Maybe I am just overthinking it but it would be great to clarify whats going on. For me it seems its just some (arbitrary) preprocessing that they are doing god knows why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cropping is indeed performed for data augmentation (i.e., cropping is one data augmentation strategy), since if one applies two different crops to the same image, one obtains two different images. E.g., from {1}:

> For data augmentation, we randomly crop input images into 24 × 24 pixels.

As a side note, the [CIFAR-10 dataset](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html) consists of 60000 *32x32* colour images in 10 classes, with 6000 images per class. This means that 24x24 cropping keeps most of the image.

---

References:

- {1} Xie, Lingxi, Jingdong Wang, Zhen Wei, Meng Wang, and Qi Tian. "DisturbLabel: Regularizing CNN on the Loss Layer." CVPR 2016.  https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=11976349396086878628&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22 ; https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.00055

Comment: maybe this is a semantics issue I have with the phrase "data set augmentation" but just randomly cropping an image is **not** augmenting the data set in any way.

Comment: @Pinocchio If you do it twice, you have two different images: for that reason it is often regarded as data augmentation.

Comment: I see. However, it only really counts as data set augmentation if you add **both** images to the "new" data set. Otherwise, its more of a pre-processing step, right? (sorry if I am being overly pedantic but I finding a bit confusing)

Comment: Also, maybe you should include in your answer more explicitly why cropping would be considered data set augmentation (since it seems to be the main issue of my question).

Comment: @Pinocchio That's correct. It's ok, I like clear definitions as well. Answer edited.

Comment: as a random side comment, randomly cropping doesn't seem like a great way to augment the data set without any further transformations. I guess its sort of making the algorithm robust to seeing the same object as if it was being viewed from different windows, but it seems rather limited. Say we did add multiple crops, I wonder if this type of transformation makes it more likely to lead to overfitting since we are essentially "memorizing" the same object.